# Parametrization of a quadriteral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The question is really simple: Is it always possible, given four points(corners) of a quadrilateral to describe these using a parametrization?

In multivariable calculus I am many times asked to calculate an integral over a rectangle or parallelogram which is easier(enclose the surface by four lines and perform a proper substitution) but I don't know how to deal with this situation if the lines are not pairwise parallel. What is the standard procedure?

Comment: ...Maybe split into rectangles/parallelogram and triangles?

Comment: Think about how to find the equation for a line between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ and then how you might integrate given only equations for lines for boundaries.